# python version conflicting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to `python`. I have installed on `OSX`, `python3` and `jupyter`. I launched a notebook, everything is fine. I installed `some_package` relying on `tafile` package. When I import `some_package`, it triggers an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tarfile'
```

The same error is triggered when I `import tarfile`

I seems that `tarfile` is related to `2.7` version. Could someone help on how to handle this ?

Comment: how did you install these packages? did you use pip or pip3?

Comment: `tarfile` is still in the Python standard library, as of Python 3.8.

Comment: hmm `tarfile` is part of the standard library and was added in version 2.6. @epsilones - you will need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @chepner so how do you explain the error regarding this package ?

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo I tried to install the package `fancyimpute` with `pip`. And this the one that pops out the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tarfile'` when I try to import it. According to your remark, I tryied to unstall the package and install it with `pip3`, I still get the same problem. Is there any problem with the some python_path ?

Comment: @epsilones My only thought is a broken Python installation that doesn't have a complete standard library installed.